A letter starting the largest number of days of the week
This is a language puzzle. Find a letter from a to z that starts the largest number of days of the week as possible. The names of the days can be in any human language and  should be in the same language for the whole week.

Good puzzles for this site should have a best final answer. It seems by your edit that you want a bunch of answers, one for each letter. That changes the question from a single optimization to a list. Perhaps you should ask separate questions for specific letters that you know to be possible.

@bobble That's a good point. I'll accept this answer.

This question is receiving close votes for being too open-ended (per bobble's comments). Perhaps you could edit to restrict to a single language rather than allowing multiple languages for a given letter - it would make the question arguably less interesting, but more on-topic, and then the accepted answer would both fit the question and be provably optimal.

@Randal'Thor done. Thank you.

In that case, voted to leave open :-)

Now, if this puzzle were about the last letters of days of the week, I think I might just have an answer... ;-)

What is the puzzle?

A score of 7 is achievable:

 In Scottish Gaelic, the days of the week are called Diluain, Dimàirt, Diciadain, Diardaoin, Dihaoine, Disatharna, and Didòmhnaich. You don't even have to use multiple languages!


That’s very interesting too!

How high can you get with another letter?

In chinese: 周一 周二 周三 周四 周五 周六 周日.  Literally "week 1, week 2, week 3, ..."

It's kind of inevitable that there'd be at least one language in the world where the part meaning "day" is at the beginning. But the objectively correct, perfect answer would have to consider ALL languages, and no one has time for it.

After some googling I found this site giving a nice overview for the names of the days of the week in many different languages. It turns out a score of 7 can be achieved with quite a few different starting letters.
Below a few, one per letter, for which I found a version using the latin alphabet.
a:

 Abkhaz: ašəax’, ao̩aš, axaš, aṗš’aš, axəaš, asabš, amċ̨yš

d:

 Aranese: deluns, dimars, dimèrcles, dijaus, diuendres, dissabte, dimenge

e:

 Albanian: e hënë, e martë, e mërkurë, e enjte, e premte, e shtunë, e diel

g:

 Tibetan: gza' zla ba, gza' mig mar, gza' lhag pa, gza' phur bu, gza' pa sangs, gza' spen pa, gza' nyi ma

h:

 Ancient Greek: hēméra Selḗnēs, hēméra Áreōs, hēméra Hermou, hēméra Diós, hēméra Aphrodítēs, hēméra Krónou, hēméra Hēlíou

j:

 Manx: Jelhune, Jemayrt, Jecrean, Jerdein, Jeheiney, Jesarn, Jedoonee

l:

 Chinese (Cantonese): láihbaaih yāt, láihbaaih yih, láihbaaih sàam, láihbaaih sei, láihbaaih nǵh, láihbaaih luhk, láihbaaih yaht

n:

 Arabic (Moroccan): nhar letnīn, nhar ttlat, nhar larbʿ, nhar lekhmīs, nhar zhzhemʿa, nhar ssebt, nhar lhedd

r:

 Maori: rāhine, rātū, rāapa, rāpare, rāmere, rāhoroi, rātapu

s:

 Chinese (Cantonese): sìngkèih yāt, sìngkèih yih, sìngkèih sàam, sìngkèih sei, sìngkèih nǵh, sìngkèih luhk, sìngkèih yaht

t:

 Central Dusun: Tadau Koiso, Tadau Koduo, Tadau Kotolu, Tadau Kaapat, Tadau Kolimo, Tadau Koonom, Tadau Koturu

u:

 Ndebele: uMvulo, uLesibili, uLesithathu, uLesine, uLesihlanu, uMgqibelo, uSonto

w:

 Thai: wan chan, wan angkān, wan phut, wan paruhat, wan suk, wan sao, wan a-tit

x:

 Chinese (Mandarin): xīngqīyī, xīngqīèr, xīngqīsān, xīngqīsì, xīngqīwǔ, xīngqīlìu, xīngqīrì/tiān

y:

Hebrew: yôm šenî, yôm šlîšî, yôm rvîʿî, yôm hamîšî, yôm šišî, yôm šabat, yôm ri'šôn


This is amazing.
